# Creating two postgres test containers but need to map to different ports

Tags: spring-boot, testcontainers

So i have a two postgres test containers:

```
   @Container
    private static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgresql1 = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:latest")
            .withDatabaseName("testdb1")
            .withUsername("testuser1")
            .withPassword("testpass1")

   @Container
    private static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgresql2 = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:latest")
            .withDatabaseName("testdb2")
            .withUsername("testuser2")
            .withPassword("testpass2")
```

I need to start these both up and running, but they both map to the same exposed port 5432. How can i set one to be mapped to a different local host port?

Comment: Have you checked that there’s no `withPort` builder option?

Comment: both use postgres port in the container but those will be map to a random port in your host. postgresql1.getJdbcUrl() and postgresql2.getJdbcUrl() will provide different ports. Is that an issue?

Comment: @EddúMeléndez on a docker network, i can give them aliases and they can have the same port ie postgres1:5432, postgres2:5432. But as part of my test i need to access them from spring app in which im currently setting localhost:5432. This would be the same for both? i cannot do that

Comment: Why do you need to link postgres1 and postgres2? If you need to consume them from an external process running spring boot app then why not use postgresql1.getJdbcUrl() and postgresql2.getJdbcUrl() as I mentioned previously? And if you are using a containerized spring boot app and it is in the same network than the dbs then you already got the answer, use the alias networks, postgres1:5432 and postgres2:5432